# pushing a controller to UINavigationController work on iPad but not on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

i got a seriously annoying problem while developing an application for iPad and iPhone.

I want my navigation controller (set by a storyboard) to push a view controller displaying some detail information.

The following piece of code once worked, but now i am experiencing a black screen when pushing the controller on an iPhone, while the exactly same code works fine on iPads. All the controllers that are used are non nil values. What happens is that the usual animation for changing view using a navigationController is displayed, but afterwards, there is only a black screen.

```
ADetailViewController* detailController =
    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ADetailViewController"];
    exposeController.data = aRealEstate;
    exposeController.appData = self.appData;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: detailController animated:YES];
```

I debuged a little into the code and noticed, that viewDidLoad of the ADetailViewController class is called, but viewDidAppear does not get called, which means that the details view is displayed (as i also noticed through the black screen :-) )

I would appreciate an kind of hint with this issue.

***UPDATE***

I managed to solve the issue by myself. The cause for this was a circular dependency i built into my delegate dependencies. This used to pop the pushed view when the rootView is going to be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You are using storyboard, so why not use segues?

All the instantiation of your view controllers is taken care of by performing the segue. You can do all the customization conveniently in `prepareForSegue:`.

I believe your error is caused by different configurations in the iPhone and iPad storyboards. If you decide to use segues, the process of pushing view controllers is much more transparent and you will be able to find the problem more easily.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. In fact the code feels better now i am using manual segues for transitions between controllers. Unfortunately this did not do anything about the "black screen" issue.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help with the issue that the navigation controller does not display any of my pushed views.

Comment: Well, then edit your question and show your code in `prepareForSegue:`.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions for you:

1. Have you tried cleaning your project?
2. Perhaps the `ADetailViewController` identifier is not a `UIViewController`, perhaps due to the fact that the Identifier has been stored in the wrong field in the storyboard for the iPhone.

Good luck

Comment: Hi,thanks for the answer. I cleaned the project several times and also deleted the app from the device. ADetailViewController is a UITableViewController. Initialization and loading of the controller is performed as expected (i debuged into it ...).